# MediaWiki python port?

Tags: php, python, mediawiki, wiki

I am trying to setup an internal wiki for our development team. It looks like mediawiki is the de facto means of doing this.

While I'm probably capable of setting this up with PHP - I was curious if there is a python port of mediawiki or a similar framework.

I'm very comfortable in PHP, and am more than happy to use it - but most of our developers prefer python. I think it would be neat to have a python wiki running.

This is just a curiosity - and not a serious issue.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: I've often lamented the lack of Python wiki engines - there's MoinMoin and ZWiki, but neither grabs me. If you go the PHP route then do try out [Dokuwiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki), which I find great for technical wikis. It has hierarchical namespaces, ACLs and a clean syntax. There's also a great Graphviz plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The de facto Python wiki application is [MoinMoin](http://moinmo.in/).

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be Python wiki's (of which [MoinMoin](http://moinmo.in/) is probably the most used - Apache, Debian, Ubuntu seem to use it).

However there's no Python MediaWiki port - the only MediaWiki 'port' is JAMWiki (a Java port), as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no Python port of MediaWiki.

Keep in mind that your developers will be *using* the wiki, not developing for it. Chances are that none of them will never need to look at the application's internals, so the language it was written in is irrelevant.

Comment: On the odd chance that we do want to change the internals, I thought it might be fun if it were in their native tongue.